# WSL_Ubuntu: 'hello-solana': error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: rust, cargo, wsl

I have seen much around this libssl.so.1.1 issue but no resolution so starting a new thread. Does anyone have line of sight into this issue? I have attempted all suggested fixes in related posts without success. Hoping that there are developments in working around this blocker.

Comment: Can you add references to the solutions you tried so far?
I'm using WSL as well and everything is running fine

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am loosing my mind over this issue. So far have tried:

Comment: I ad a breakthrough and found this solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuJPpCfuSJ0 which worked however now I receive this error: failed to select a version for the requirement `serde_with = "^3.0.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 1.14.0, 1.13.0, 1.12.1, ...

Comment: well this error is at least explicit: just change the version of the package. It could also be a typo in the crate's name, checks hyphens and underscores

Comment: check out this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) thread for a full solution

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `libssl-dev` package via `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

If that didn't work then run the command series of commands

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

This command won't run as being outdated
here is updated one, worked for me:

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23_amd64.deb
```